# How to go back to previously defined function in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a function:

```
(defun function-name (&optional args) ... <unknown content>)
```

I redefine it with

```
(defun function-name (&optional args) ... my own content)
```

Can I somehow after some time remove my own version of `function-name` and stay with the first one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, you cannot**.

### Save/Restore

You can save the definition yourself before redefining the function:

**Common Lisp**:

```
(defparameter *old-def* (fdefinition 'function-name))
(defun function-name ...)
...
(setf (fdefinition 'function-name) *old-def*)
```

**Emacs Lisp**:

```
(defconst *old-def* (symbol-function 'function-name))
(defun function-name ...)
...
(fset 'function-name *old-def*)
```

### Reload

Or, if you know where the function was defined, you can reload the definition:

**Common Lisp**:

```
(load "file-name")
```

**Emacs Lisp**: same as above or <kbd>M-x load-library RET</kbd>.

### Reeval

Or, if you know the original definition, you can reevaluate it, by pasting it at the **Common Lisp** prompt or by visiting the file with the definition in **Emacs** and evaluating the defun using <kbd>C-M-x</kbd>, as suggested by @Drew in a comment.

Comment: Can you also provide Emacs Lisp version? There is no `defparameter` and `fdefinition`

Comment: Do you have `fdefinition` in Emacs?

Comment: Since you (OP) refer to the first definition as having "unknown content", presumably the original definition of the function is provided either as part of Emacs or in some 3rd-party library. In that case, `load-library` for that library is a good approach. If for some reason you do not want to reload all of that library's code then you can just visit the library, put the cursor on/in the definition, and use `C-M-x` to reevaluate it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that it's risky to redefine other libraries' or Emacs' own functions, since you don't know what else depends on them working exactly as expected. If at all possible, use a different name. If not, provide copious documentation warning prominently about the redefinitions. Also, did you check first whether the existing function can be tweaked to your satisfaction using predefined hooks that run before or after it or by customizing any particular user options?

Answer (score 1):

Not the way you do it, but you can get what you want by using an advice instead of a new definition.  E.g.

```
(defadvice function-name (around my-overrride activate)
  ... my own content)
```

after the above you can recover the old behavior by deactivating the advice.  Using the new advice system in Emacs-24.4 this would look like:

```
(defun my-function-name (&optional args) ... my own content)
(add-advice 'function-name :override #'my-function-name)
```

which can be reverted with

```
(remove-advice 'function-name #'my-function-name)
```