# Save value of old function in elisp to call

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a function:

```
(defun alternate-narrow-to-region (start end)
   (message "Hi!")
   (narrow-to-region start end))
```

I want all uses of narrow-to-region, except for the one in this function body, to call alternate-narrow-to-region (so narrow-to-defun, narrow-to-page, direct calls to narrow-to-region, end up calling alternate-narrow-to-region).

How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preferred method of overriding an emacs lisp function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717103/preferred-method-of-overriding-an-emacs-lisp-function)

Comment: Related thread: [how to go back to previously defined function in emacs lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085413/how-to-go-back-to-previously-defined-function-in-emacs-lisp).  You could probably `(defconst orig-narrow-to-region (symbol-function 'narrow-to-region))` and then try `(funcall orig-narrow-to-region start end)` within your new version.  Not sure if it would override the originals if callers have been byte-compiled (as with your prior question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246901/advice-only-applies-in-all-cases-after-function-calling-advised-function-is-re-e).

Comment: If this question gets closed then please consider moving #1 of my answer to the duplicate page. That page does not mention `defalias`, which is the preferred way to do this (not `fset`).

Comment: This is what advice is for. Unless there is no way to solve your problem without modifying the internal structure of the original function, use advice.

Comment: Turns out that advice won't work for this specific problem with `narrow-to-region` (see the referenced thread in my first comment).

Answer (score 1):

1. To save the original definition (which is in your question title but not in the text), use `defalias`:

   (defalias 'ORIGINAL-narrow-to-region (symbol-function 'narrow-to-region)
       "My doc string about this.")

   Note that in this case you do ***not*** want to use this:

   (defalias 'FOREVER-narrow-to-region 'narrow-to-region
       "My doc string about this.")

   What you want to do is copy the function definition at a given point in time.  The latter use of `defalias` instead has the effect of pointing `FOREVER-narrow-to-region` to whatever the current definition of `narrow-to-region` is.  If you redefine `narrow-to-region` then it will point to the new definition, which is presumably not what you want in this case.
2. As for the question implied by your text, the answer is that you cannot.  You cannot get Emacs to always use your function instead of `narrow-to-region`. This is explained at your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25246901/729907): code that calls `narrow-to-region` and is compiled will continue to (in effect) call the original `narrow-to-region`. (It is not really called at all. Its code is effectively inlined.)
3. If you wanted to get Emacs to use a replacement command only when called interactively, you could of course remap the original command's key bindings to the replacment.  But that does not seem to be the case here.